# expo eas build failing

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

[image]
I am new to react native and read the docs to build the apk with eas build --platform android
After all steps my eas build fails at run gradlew and gives these 2 errors:

1. Could not set property 'classifier'for task
2. compileSdkVersion is not specified.

I am running a managed workflow with no native code. Here is my [complete code](https://github.com/Megahedron69/EcoSorter).Rest of the steps have a green tick and all dependencies are updated to correct version

Comment: Did you find a way to debug your error?

Comment: yes I deleted the expo gl cpp package and it worked